# Remove Klipper from Kubuntu

Tags: apt, kubuntu

How can I remove `klipper` from Kubuntu 18.04?

I tried `apt remove klipper` but `Package 'klipper' is not installed, so not removed`. I tried to search installed packages with `apt list --installed | grep -i clip`, `apt list --installed | grep -i klip` etc. but no result.

Is there a way to remove it? If not, can I disable it?

Comment: are you sure that it's even installed. If you can open the app may be it's added to one of the paths. Type `echo $PATH` and check each folder for the presense of `klipper` or may be `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications` for a .desktop file that corresponds to the package

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Klipper" is part of the `plasma-workspace` package and cannot be uninstalled without removing all of KDE.

It can be disabled by going to System Tray settings > General > Extra Items.  Uncheck "Clipboard".

[image: screenshot]

Comment: For System Tray Settings - Right click on the arrow in the task bar

Comment: On Kubuntu 21.10, one needs to go to Entries÷System Services and set "Clipboard" to disabled.