# How to make copyq default in KDE Kubuntu and replace Klipper?

Tags: kubuntu, clipboard, clipboard-manager

I'm new to (K)ubuntu. How do I turn off the Default clipboard manager (Klipper) in KDE and make copyq default.

Comment: See [Remove Klipper from Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1032985/567307). Once Klipper is disabled, I suppose you can enable copyq "normally".